# Display is showing a Red Tint

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a Gtx 1050ti, and my display is showing a red tint just after I sign in into my pc.

I tried changing the settings, Nvidia control panel, night light and even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers.

It just keep happening again, the screen gets to normal after I uninstall the driver and even restart my pc. But as soon as I reinstall any nvidia driver, latest or outdated, the tint comes back.

So I know, the problem is maybe with the driver.

If anyone can answer, it would help or maybe I might have to try doing a clean installation.

[image: Image with more red than it should have]

Comment: When you reinstall the nVidia driver, are you doing so with clean settings?

Comment: Can you explain it.

Comment: I generally just Install through the Game Ready Driver downloaded locally.

Comment: @TejasKhurana If you choose the "Custom" installation option, there will be a checkbox to do a clean installation.

Comment: Thanks, let me try :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton well unfortunately It didn't work

Comment: @TejasKhurana Can you find a colour profile for your monitor from its manufacturer? And/or, you can use the Windows "Colour Management" control panel.

Comment: Have you thought of a hardware problem, most notably the display cable? Replace it with a "known good" one. One or more wire might be broken or torn from the plug (but not the Red one).

Comment: @AndrewMorton have tried that earlier, didn't work.

Comment: @user1016274 I think its a driver issue, cause the display works super fine without an Nvidia Driver, only if I install or even clean install the Nvidia driver, the display gets black as the driver installs and tinted again. 

I have downloaded an official Windows10 image, so II might do another clean install

Comment: @TejasKhurana Is the monitor correctly identified in the Nvidia control panel?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yess it was, currently I have uninstalled the driver, and haven't restarted the pc.

Comment: @TejasKhurana It's a bit strange that the Spotify logo has its green. How much trying things are you willing to do? E.g. does your computer's motherboard have a video output that you can try? Have you tried https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html ?

Comment: let me see, although will it help if I clean install my windows again? @AndrewMorton

Comment: @TejasKhurana I didn't want to suggest re-installing Windows just in case you have some software that would need its license numbers typed in again or something like that, but otherwise that does often fix a lot of problems.

Comment: Problem is with your gpu or nvidia settings. Not with driver. Test GPU on another pc or reset your windows. Format data on your pc. Or Use IObit uninstaller to clean uninstall nvidia drivers and settings. Then Install your driver via Geforce Experience..

Answer (score 0):

After doing every single thing, even after using DDU to uninstall nvidia graphics card which still resulted in nothing.

Resetting Windows only keeping everything else solved the issue. So if anyone is facing this, keep a backup and windows Iso and apps and drivers locally backed and be ready to reset your pc once and for all

Answer (score 0):

The "Night Light" setting got turned on and set to "Max Strength" by accident.

You can tell its this because its independent of the display drivers, so uninstalling and re-installing the drivers will not fix the problem, only mask it because each time you are changing drivers you are also resetting some of the display settings including the Night Light setting that gets changed for some reason. The red tint only gets applied after you log in since thats when your user settings in Windows are loaded.

Re-installing Windows only helped because it also leaves Night Light off by default, or at least puts the settings back to the default, on a new install.

As a side note, I have experienced the same thing in Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 when changing the Nvidia graphics drivers around. Ubuntu desktop includes a similar feature these days.